# How to create crystals on a sea bed like this?

Tags: particles, shaders

I am creating a layer of crystals on a sea bed in Blender 3.5.

To create crystals on the sea bed, did the following steps:

1. Created multiple particle systems (4 particle system) on the same plane. Used hair setting.
2. For each particle system, used different objects as instance.
3. In weight mode, created different spread for each particle system
4. Material – Used Color Ramp with Glassy BSDF to to give crystal look.
5. Render Engine - Cycles

Requirement

1. From top the layer should look like stars with different coloured emissions spread on a sea bed, and as we move closer, emission stays but crystals start appearing.

Issues faced

1. Unable to get glow and starry effect on the particles. Tried composting, but didn't get the effect with that also.
2. Crystals (particles) at some places are looking very clustered and shape is distorted.

Material Used Screenshot (Same material nodes have been used on all crystal)

### Project

I am creating a layer of crystals on a sea bed in Blender 3.5.
The sea bed would have sand particles and crystals spread on it.

To create crystals on the sea bed, did the following steps:

1. Created multiple particle systems (4 particle system) on the same plane. Used hair setting.
2. For each particle system, used different objects as instance.
3. In weight mode, created different spread for each particle system
   4.Material – Used Color Ramp with Glassy BSDF to to give crystal look.
4. Render Engine - Cycles

Requirement

1. From top the layer should look like stars with different coloured emissions spread on a sea bed, and as we move closer, emission stays but crystals start appearing.
2. Sand bed has to be created

Issues faced

1. Unable to get glow and starry effect on the particles. Tried composting, but didn't get the effect with that also.
2. Crystals (particles) at some places are looking very clustered and shape is distorted.
3. Sand bed : How to add sand particles with different golden or other shades in different areas. Help here also will be appreciated.

Attachments

1. Material Used Screenshot (Same material nodes have been used on all crystal)
   [image]
2. Render Image ( Please ignore the background -HDRI image use to get right colors for a sea bed)
   [image]
3. Ref Image for the cystals ( though not exact but something similar)
   [image]
4. Blender 3.5 File - Unable to find how to attach blender file here directly

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com ... copy paste given code via edit into your question.

Answer (score 2):

In these days people use geometry nodes (instead of particle system) ... so here is one quick ...

[image]
[image]

**Material – Sand** with some random instances set to emit light
[image]
[image]

**Material - Gems** ...
[image]
[image]

Simple composite with Glare node ...
[image]
[image]